# importing json module in visual studio code not working

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I'm working with an api for a discord bot and it doesn't let me import json in vs code. I'm using python 3.9.1 and it gives me this message:

```
"json" is not accessed Pylance
```

On the import section json displays with faded color.

Comment: -When I run "import json" in VS Code, there is no such error. Could you still not run this code after installing this module in the python environment of VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

this module can't be resolved within your configured python environment. maybe your configuration is wrong or the module isn't installed in that environment. If you don't care about this warning, you can disable it in the settings

[check this out](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings)